# ssh fails with "could not find home directory" (which exists and has permissions) even while a local terminal logs the same user in

Tags: ssh, permissions, terminal, login, useradd

I have a bizarre problem where ssh does not find a home directory for some users (that exists), yet the same user can login directly on my machine via a local terminal.

### Details follow:

I maintain a server (server.domain.edu) where my students sftp in to submit homeworks/etc. The machine runs Fedora Linux 22. As an initial setup, I get them to ssh into the server and change their default password.

I set up their accounts with:

```
useradd -s /bin/changepasswd -p `openssl passwd -1 studentname` studentuname
```

changepasswd is a simple shell script that prints a few instructions, and calls on passwd. Permissions for `/bin/changepasswd` is 755, and the owner:group are root:root

Now, I change ownership and group of /`home/studentname` (to avoid problems with sftp). `ls -ld /home/studentname` yields

```
drwxr-xr-x. 24 root teacher 4096 Jan 18 13:58 studentname
```

The mystery is that I created accounts for about a dozen students with exactly the same setup. For some of them, it works as expected (they log in, and the system runs changepasswd and the session terminates with the script). For the rest, the following happens:

```
ssh studentname@server.domain.edu

Could not chdir to home directory /home/studentname: No such file or directory
/bin/changepasswd: No such file or directory
Connection to server.domain.edu closed.
```

On the other hand, if the same user who had a problem with ssh uses a local terminal on the server (the local text login), everything runs as expected without the above error messages. The ssh problem exists whether they use clients like putty/ssh command from mac or even ssh to the server from an xterm on the server (instead of directly logging in locally).

### sshd_config file:

sshd_config has one thing out of ordinary---for every studentname I have:

Match Group studentname
ForceCommand /bin/changepasswd
ChrootDirectory /home/studentname
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no

Again, note that this actually works for some students but not others. The rest of the sshd_config file is the default one.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: What Linux/OS? What interesting is in `sshd_config`?

Comment: If it's Linux what does the SSH daemon tell you during logon (`/var/log/auth` on Debian; may be elsewhere on RH derived systems)

Comment: The server runs Fedora linux 22. sshd_config has one thing out of ordinary---for every studentname I have:

Match Group studentname
ForceCommand /bin/changepasswd
ChrootDirectory /home/studentname
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no

Comment: The `ChrootDirectory /home/studentname` would explain `/bin/changepasswd: No such file or directory` Unless every student has a `/home/studentname/bin/changepasswd`.

Comment: read the logs, on server and run ssh in debug mode, to get client side logs.

Comment: And it does not matter that /bin/changepasswd comes before the chroot? That could also explain why it says /home/studentname not found. Let me try fixing this---but the question I would still have is, why did it work for half the students?

Comment: richard, thanks a lot---removing the chroot directory works. I don't need it for ssh, only for sftp (which I give access to after they change their password). Only remaining mystery is why it worked for some. I kind of feel silly right now---but I think it was somehow stuck in my head that ssh would go line by line in the config file (so forcecommand line first, then chroot)